# In Gedit, which syntax highlighting option is for Python 3.x?

Tags: python, gedit

Gedit has two options for syntax highlighting for Python:

- Python
- Python2

Is the "Python" option for:

1. *Older* versions of Python *less than* version 2 (ex. 1.6, 1.5, ...)

   ...or...
2. *Newer* versions of Python *greater than* version 2 (ex. 3.0, 3.1, 3.9, ...)

In other words, to do syntax highlighting for Python 3.9, which of the two options should I select?

I am using Gedit version 40.1-1 in Ubuntu 21.10. Here is a screenshot of Gedit's syntax highlighting options menu:

[image: Gedit Syntax Highlighting Options Menu]

Comment: "Python" option will work for you (I am using it from a lot of time I don't think that there is a problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from Python 1.x being completely irrelevant these days (do you expect the "Python console" in gedit to run Python 1?), if you need confirmation, here's the defining line for "Python" in the [GtkSourceView source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtksourceview/-/blob/master/data/language-specs/python3.lang#L23):

```
<language id="python3" name="Python" version="2.0" _section="Script">
```

[GtkSourceView](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView) is the library used by gedit for syntax highlighting.